# html - background image slow to load

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that is ~300kb in size.

For some reason it will not load on my webpage even after several minutes.
This is the code where I am using the background image. It is in the same level as my webpage.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is the image too large..?
Thanks.

```
body {
background-color: #D2C7AC;
background-image:url('background.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I think the problem is solved. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Just a project I am working on. Did the background load for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image url should be in quotes.

```
background-image:url('background.jpg');
```

You can check the network tab in the developer tools to make sure that the image is being found correctly as well (make sure it doesn't return a 404).

Comment: Updated, still running into the problem.

Comment: Did you check to see if the image is being requested? If you open up the developer tools and go to the Network tab you should see something that looks like `GET background.jpg` and should have a status of 200 or 304. If it has a status of 404 it means the image can't be found (bad url). If it's 200 or 304 then there is something else in your html or css that is preventing the image from being displayed.

Comment: On the link you posted, I see the image being displayed properly, it's just really slow to load.  It shouldn't be taking that long to download 300 kb, something else is wrong...

Comment: Not sure if I have those tools, I renamed the webpage to something else and clicked on the background.jpg from my index. The image loaded fine. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It's loading just fine, just really, really slowly.  Something is up with the internet connection that is serving your site. AFter 5 minutes I've downloaded 287kb of it.

Comment: Is it loading for you now? I have the image loaded on my screen now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Fiddler to investigate:

http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

It will help you see exactly what's happening in the background.